# Automatically convert SNMP service to REST API

Tags: rest, snmp

I've some equipment which interface is both CLI and SNMP. The SNMP implements custom MIBs.

I want to expose this SNMP interface as a REST API and I wonder if there is any tool that can read a MIB and automatically create a REST API.

My question is: There is a tool (or a process) to create a REST API based on the MIB specifications ?

Comment: Technically it is doable, but I don't think many people would do so. You still have lots of legacy code to migrate (as the objects underlying implementation is in native language, such as C/C++ or else), which won't be processed by such a tool easily.

Comment: I was thinking more about a proxy. It access the SNMP on localhost and  forward it to the HTTP rest . No code change, easy to do but worse performance.

Answer (score 3):

I just 5 minutes ago, stumbled upon this: 
[RESTful SNMP Over HTTP: Part I](https://dzone.com/articles/restful-snmp-over-http)

> The problem is finding a way to publish the internal MIB (Management Information Base) data structure of a network device in a safe and uniform way through a more commonly available protocol as HTTP(S) (HyperText Transfer Protocol [Secure]).

Comment: That article is a good discussion of how various aspects of SNMP map to a REST API, but there isn't an actual implementation, is there?

Comment: If there was one, it would be highly useful